# Easiest way to play SOUND with MONO on OSX

Tags: c#, macos, audio, mono

I am writing a simple timer app for OSX10.6 using Mono. How can I play an alarm sound (it may be a wav/mp3 file or something else)?

I tried several ways, unfortunately none did work:

1. [NSSound](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=C%3aMonoMac.AppKit.NSSound%28System.String,System.Boolean%29) seems to be not supported by Mono yet.

   ```
   MonoMac.AppKit.NSSound alarm = new MonoMac.AppKit.NSSound("alarm.wav");
   alarm.Play();
   ```
2. Using a `SoundPlayer` didn't work either:

   ```
   System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer("alarm.wav");
   player.PlaySync();
   ```
3. I was able to play a sound by opening a `System.Diagnostics.Process` and then use the OSX command line command `afplay`. Unfortunately, this command opens in a new terminal window, which is quite annoying in a GUI app.

I realize there are CoreAudio bindings in Mono. But I have not figured out how to use them to play a sound.

Comment: How easy is it to access a general purpose C library from mono? It's probably easy to use PortAudio than CoreAudio. For example, the blocking I/O is much easier. I'm sure there's an even easier way, but if all else fails....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong NSSound constructor is all.

[`new MonoMac.AppKit.NSSound("alarm.wav")`](http://api.xamarin.com/?link=C%3aMonoMac.AppKit.NSSound%28MonoMac.Foundation.NSData%29) expects an `NSData` (implicitly cast from `string`), you want to use [`new NSSound(string, bool)`](http://api.xamarin.com/?link=C%3aMonoMac.AppKit.NSSound%28System.String,System.Boolean%29).  Probably want to pass `false` for the second parameter.

I threw together a quicky test project (based on the default MonoMac project)  to confirm this works:

```
public override void FinishedLaunching (NSObject notification)
{
  mainWindowController = new MainWindowController ();
  mainWindowController.Window.MakeKeyAndOrderFront (this);

  // Only lines added
  var sound = new NSSound("/Users/kevinmontrose/Desktop/bear_growl_y.wav", byRef: false);

  sound.Play();
}
```